# Capistrano Deploy therubyracer bundle error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-ec2, capistrano, therubyracer

I am having issues deploying my site to my EC2 instance using capistrano. Bundle install, gem install therubyracer (and libv8) with a variety of gem versions all work fine. The bundle only fails with cap deploy. i have tried uninstalling and reinstalling certain gems (on both my local host and EC2 instance), along with a lot of other suggestions but nothing seems to work.

I am using Rails 4 and Capistrano 2.15

My errors resulting from

```
cap deploy
```

are

```
servers: ["ip address"]
[ip address] executing command
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
/usr/bin/ruby2.0 extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lpthread... yes
Warning! Unable to load libv8 ~> 3.16.14.
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib64
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/usr/bin/ruby2.0
--with-pthreadlib
--without-pthreadlib
--enable-debug
--disable-debug
/usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file --     libv8 (LoadError)
from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from extconf.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

Relevant Gemfile excerpt:

```
gem 'therubyracer', '~> 0.12.1'
gem 'libv8', '~> 3.16.14.3', :platform => :ruby
```

Lastly, the suggested  mkmf.log file contains the below code:

```
have_library: checking for main() in -lpthread... -------------------- yes

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/ruby/2.0 -I/usr/include/ruby/2.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby/2.0 -I.    -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -mtune=generic -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib64 -L. -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic  -m64   -L/usr/lib64/ruby/2.0 -lruby  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/ruby/2.0 -I/usr/include/ruby/2.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby/2.0 -I.    -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -mtune=generic -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib64 -L. -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic  -m64   -L/usr/lib64/ruby/2.0 -lruby -lpthread  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
conftest.c:5:57: error: ‘main’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))main; return 0; }
                                                         ^
conftest.c:5:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
conftest.c:5:32: warning: variable ‘p’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
 int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))main; return 0; }
                                ^
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))main; return 0; }
 6: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 7: {
 8:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 9:     printf("%p", &t);
10:   }
11: 
12:   return 0;
13: }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/ruby/2.0 -I/usr/include/ruby/2.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby/2.0 -I.    -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -mtune=generic -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib64 -L. -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic  -m64   -L/usr/lib64/ruby/2.0 -lruby -lpthread  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
conftest.c:5:1: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘main’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 int t(void) { main(); return 0; }
 ^
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int t(void) { main(); return 0; }
 6: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 7: {
 8:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 9:     printf("%p", &t);
10:   }
11: 
12:   return 0;
13: }
/* end */
```

Comment: it looks like libv8 is not installed, and hence therubyracer gem is failing during building the native extension here: https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer/blob/master/ext/v8/extconf.rb#L29. Does running bundle install on the EC2 instance work?

Comment: Yes running on ec2 works, running on my local host works, but the bundle install that comes from running cap deploy fails